# Argument labels '(of:, with:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to update my data to firebase but its showing this error "Argument labels '(of:, with:)' do not match any available overloads"

```
 func UpdateTaskWithName(name:String,date:String, completionHandler:@escaping ((_ success:Bool)->Void)){
    if let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        self.ref.child("WeightTracker")
            .child(userid)
            .queryOrdered(byChild: "date")
            .queryEqual(toValue: date)
            .observe(of: .value, with: {snapshot in     // error showing here
                self.ref.child("WeightTracker").child(userid).child(snapshot.children.key).child("weight").setValue(name)
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) shows the syntax as: `postRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in`.

Comment: so what i have to change in this code?

Comment: Delete `of:` from `.observe(of: .value, with: {snapshot`

Comment: then its showing "Unable to infer closure type in the current context" this error

Comment: Maybe `.value` is not what you think it is, try with the full name

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **listen to data** use
 `.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in`

If you want to **read once** use
`.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in`